# Excel - The difference between two dates in the specified range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate the duration of a given event (in hours), but only taking into account the time between the `hour Y` and the `hour X`.

Example:

> The event lasted from 7:00 to 14:00, but the result must be only the number of hours between 10:00 and 12:00.

Do you have any tips how to solve it?

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you need to know the `hour` difference between 10 am and 12 pm?

Comment: Yes, but I have problem when event is short than range hours. Or start time is earlier than range.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, please elaborate further?

Comment: Event time: 7:00 - 11:00. Hour range 10:00 - 12:00. Result should give us 1 hour.

Comment: What I don't understand is, how can the result be 1 hour, because the difference between 10am and 12pm is 2 hours? What other factors are you not mentioning maybe?

Answer (score 2):

So you need calculating the overlap of two time ranges?

Example:

[image]

Formula in `G2` downwards:

```
=MAX(0,MIN(B2,E2)-MAX(A2,D2))
```